# jquery UI simple context menu, callable from button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm looking for some combination of a plugin or clever programming technique that will allow me to have a context-style menu in jQuery but rather than actually triggering it from a right-click, I'd like to be able to have it triggered from a button that can potentially move to different locations on my window. I can handle the part of the button itself moving without much trouble. My requirements are:

- It should be compatible with jQuery UI 1.8 and my custom themeroller-generated theme
- It needs to be relocatable
- I either need to have it execute a callback when an element is selected, or have it honor the `href` on any `a` tags that make up the menu elements

I looked at [Selectmenu](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu) and it's close, but it seems to want to always show the currently selected item, which is not quite what I want. Also I had to hack around it in an ugly way to make it relocate properly.

[This blog post](http://tahirhassan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jquery-context-menu.html) is also pretty close but the jsEvent.clientX and jsEvent.clientY don't put the dialog in the right place and I'm a little stuck as to what to do about that. Also I don't really want the options to be buttons. The menu-ish plugins have them looking right.

[This plugin here](https://github.com/basti1253/jQueryUI-contextmenu) is pretty much exactly what I want (I'd have to add the bit about the button, but it doesn't look too hard). But that requires jQuery UI 1.9.

Any thoughts? It may be that this is just such a rare requirement that I have to roll my own, but somehow that seems surprising and I feel like I might be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The menu plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Menu) you mentioned last seems to work fine with jQuery UI 1.8.x, but not jQuery UI 1.7.x.

- jQ-UI 1.8.7: http://jsfiddle.net/william/xxGUW/
- jQ-UI 1.8.9: http://jsfiddle.net/william/xxGUW/1/
- jQ-UI 1.8.14: http://jsfiddle.net/william/xxGUW/2/
- jQ-UI 1.7.2 (broken): http://jsfiddle.net/william/xxGUW/3/

Comment: I saw that plugin, but its API doesn't seem to line up with what's documented [here](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Menu) - see http://jsfiddle.net/xxGUW/4/ and it also doesn't seem to have the "pop open in different locations when triggered" feature I need.

Comment: Well, in the end, I was able to get the "hidden" menu plugin in 1.8 to work more or less well enough for my purposes. Since that is what this answer recommends, I'll accept it. Essentially my mistake was trying to move it in the DOM when a judicious application of `position()` was all that was needed.

Comment: Feel free to update my answer with your final solution, so it would benefit other users.

Answer (score 4):

I like this plugin. It seems that is more compatible than jQueryUI-contextmenu.
Is a fork of jQueryUI-contextmenu actually
[jQuery-contextMenu](http://addyosmani.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/index.html)

I liked it because it has more examples, and it says that only use one footprint in memory so it consume less resources in comparison to others. Works with +jquery 1.6 and don't necessarily need html markup,